# having a problem with backtesting time code

Tags: pine-script

“I’m making a indicator. I want to be able to backtest it.”

”This is what i have already tried”

```
fromDay   = input(defval= 1, title="fromDay",minval= 1, maxval= 31)
fromMonth = input(defval= 1, title="fromMonth",minval= 1, maxval= 12)
fromYear  = input(defval= 1, title="fromYear",minval= 1017)

toDay     = 1 //input(defval= 1, title="toDay",minval= 1, maxval= 31)
toMonth   = 1 //input(defval= 1, title="toMonth",minval=1, maxval= 31)
toYear    = 9999 //input(defval= 9999, title="toYear",minval= 9999)

Start     = timestamp(fromDay , FromMonth , fromYear , 00 , 00) //start 
of window
Finish    = timestamp(toDay , toMonth , toYear , 00 , 00)       //end 
of window
Window()  => time => Start and time <= Finish ? true : false //create 
the function "within the window of time"
```

“This is the error massage i got.
syntax error at input =>. i got the error at the Window() function”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use your code, this is proper syntax:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
fromDay   = input(defval= 1, title="fromDay",minval= 1, maxval= 31)
fromMonth = input(defval= 1, title="fromMonth",minval= 1, maxval= 12)
fromYear  = input(defval= 1017, title="fromYear",minval= 1017)

toDay     = 1 //input(defval= 1, title="toDay",minval= 1, maxval= 31)
toMonth   = 1 //input(defval= 1, title="toMonth",minval=1, maxval= 31)
toYear    = 9999 //input(defval= 9999, title="toYear",minval= 9999)

Start     = timestamp(fromYear , fromMonth , fromDay , 00 , 00) //start  of window
Finish    = timestamp(toYear , toMonth , toDay , 00 , 00)       //end  of window
Window()  => time >= Start and time <= Finish ? true : false //create the function "within the window of time"

plot(Window()?1:0)
```